# What is the Best way to join data from elastic search and MySQL for pagination?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, pagination

I'm working on an application having **users** data in elastic search and **Users cars** data in MySQL.

Requirement: Pagination view for users cars of a particular state like below

**View**

**State**: New York

User id 1 | UserCar id 1

User id 1 | UserCar id 2

User id 3 | UserCar id 10

User id 4 | UserCar id 15

A single user may have any number of cars.

I thought of the below two approaches.

1) Fetch all the users from the given state from Elastic search and then Fetch all the cars of those users from MySQL and then based on the page number, send the split data.

2) Fetch user by user from elastic search and then fetch that user cars from MySQL and keep doing till the time you reach the number of records of that page.

I think both the above methods are inefficient. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would get the users page from ES (just the single required page), and then enrich it with the needed cars info from DB, just the relevant cars.

In order to speed up the second phase of the cars enrichments, I recommend having a cache - whether full DB in memory, or just LRU.

So, one fetch from ES of the right page and enrichment in memory of the relevant cars. This should be efficient.

Comment: But how would we know the right page data? Cars for a user is not constant, one user may have 20 cars and the other may have 3 and the other 0. So if we have a page size of 10, first two pages will be taken up by first user. As elastic search doesn't know about this, how can we fetch the right page data from ES?

Comment: your query to ES should fetch X users, by a sort order of your choice, and only a page (meaning a request have a 'from' & 'size' parameters). getting a page of users from ES is consistent and deterministic - every page will contain exactly X users. Then, you use an in-memory cache for cars, with a cache by-car-id, you can get direct access to the cars you need. and enrich the X users with their cars info in memory.

Comment: But the page is not for X users, it is for X UsersCars. So in that case we may need to query ES and MySQL to get X records.

Comment: So, if you wish to get X usersCars, so go ahead and fetch those X from MySQL, for the needed page. Then extract all the users which you need to enrich their info from ES, then run a single mget to get the users from ES. this way you have one DB fetch and one query to ES

Comment: But as is stated in the question, only users of a specific state needs to be retrieved and that state won't be there in the MySQL.

Comment: Ok, so in this case I would go with something similar to the option 2 you suggested - fetch the users from ES, in either paging OR scroll, and then enrich with the cars info from DB, iterate on this until getting a full page (it should be enough to bring a single large page of users from ES, but you might need to iterate if they don't have enough cars).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create user cars table on the browser, then get those cars data left join with user-cars relational table from MYSQL using limit & offset. here i am assuming you are using server-side datatable.

Then get the particular users data from ES because getting data from ES is faster. next, from client end, you need to append or update the table column using JS.

ES query should be like this :

```
GET /users/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter" : {
                "terms" : { 
                    "id" : [1, 2, 3]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We don't know how many users to fetch on the first hand, because ES doesn't have the cars data.

Comment: your MySQL has user and cars relational table I guess. so can't you get paginated user ids and send them to ES. maybe my approach is wrong but just trying to help. if you want to show first 10 cars with the related user, you will have both cars id & users id from some relational table(user-car). send those user ids to ES to get the detail of user. Hence every time you load more data, you can use the same method. the code will be little complex from JS I think, but I think it will work. all the best and please update what solution you find. It can help me & others.

Comment: But the point is, we need to show only users from a specific state. State information is there in ES. I didn't find a solution yet, will update if i get.